# Is there any difference  between ui:fragment and s:fragment?

Tags: jsf, seam, facelets, jsf-1.2

What's the difference between `<ui:fragment>` and `<s:fragment>` ? I use these two tag libraries interchangeably for conditional rendering (using the rendered attribute although I can't find any documentation that states "rendered" is a valid attribute for ui:fragment)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `rendered` is the only difference.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm usign facelets with jsf 1.2 and the attribute "rendered" with ui:fragment works correctly, nevertheless i can't find any official documentation stating that "rendered" is a valid attribute for the ui:fragment tag

Comment: That attribute was indeed overlooked in the tag declaration file. They fixed it for JSF 2.1. See also http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/fragment.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be late to the party. I agree with Shervin. The "rendered" attribute on ui:fragment isn't documented, but seems to work. I'm using JSF 1.2 on JBoss 4.2.3.

I think you should use the Seam tag if you're using Seam. I'm just working with plain JSF though, so I don't have a choice.